# How to batch GitHub PR post-review comments notifications?

Tags: github, review

When reviewing PR on GitHub, the is a brilliant option for reviewer
to add multiple comments as pending, and then submit them to the author as a review with one notification.

Each comment has it’s own option Reply and Resolve Conversation.
E.g. if review has 10 comments, and author wants to reply for 9 of them ‘updated in commit 12345’,
reviewer will receive notifications for each of them, which can be quite annoying.

Is it possible  to make pending such post-review comments and submit them as a single notification?

If not, I will submit a feature request to GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

I found existing GitHub [Feature request: writing PR comments in batch #1276](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1276)

and posted a workaround

> The problem you described is correct if an author is using main
> “conversation” tab to reply to each reviewer’s comment. As a
> workaround author can switch to “Files changed” tab, and there is an
> option to keep all comments as “pending” and then submit all of them
> at once(simulating review of own PR)
>
> It’s definitely not intuitive, and I would appreciate if GitHub will
> implement it properly for “conversation” tab